# Query firebase username

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query username from firebase, its not fetching the query and i get this log does anyone know what this means?

> Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn":
>   "contacts/t25ha71bw0gRIU9HRhY2ecGSAS03" at /users to your security
>   rules for better performance

**Rules on Firebase**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "(auth != null)",
    ".write": "(auth != null)",
    "location":{
      "$uid": {
        ".indexOn": ["lat","long"] 
      }
    },
    "events": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "(auth != null) && !data.child('deleted').exists()",
        ".write": "(auth != null)",
        ".indexOn": ["name", "owner"]
      }
    },
    "groups": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "(auth != null) && !data.child('deleted').exists()",
        ".indexOn": ["name", "members", "owner"]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "(auth != null) && !data.child('deleted').exists()",
        "contacts" : {
          ".indexOn": ".value"
        },
        ".indexOn": ["username"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query**

```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)     {
    updateSearchResult(text: searchText)
    guard !searchText.isEmpty else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) {
        if self.contactType == .contact {
            AppFirRef.userRef.queryOrdered(byChild:"username")
                .queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
                .queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\\uf8ff")
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                var contacts = Set<LAContact>()
                for case let snap as FIRDataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                    guard let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] else { continue }
                    let item = LAContact(value: value)
                    contacts.insert(item)
                }
                let filteredItems = self.filteredItems as! [LAContact]
                let filtereSet = contacts.union(filteredItems)
                self.filteredItems = Array(filtereSet)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**AppFirRef**

```
final class AppFirRef {
static let baseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    static var currentUserRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
        guard let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else { return nil }
        return userRef.child(user.uid)
    }
    static var userRef = baseRef.child("users")
    static var eventRef = baseRef.child("events")
    static var groupRef = baseRef.child("groups")
    static var messageRef = baseRef.child("messages")
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that initializes `AppFirRef.userRef`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited it

Comment: You might not have permission to read from `/users`. See this [Stack Overflow documentation topic on how to detect read errors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24788/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-ios#t=201702111837434086084). Also make sure that the code you share is minimal-and-complete. For example: what is the value of `searchText`? It's easiest to help you if you reproduce the problem in a single method that doesn't take parameters and accesses no fields.

Comment: Are you implementing a searchBar where the user types and partial matches of usernames are presented? It looks like you are performing a search with each keystroke. If so, that code may be overly complex - also using DispatchQueue is going to cause issues down the road and most importantly Firebase doesn't have a partial match function built in so it has to be implemented through the Firebase structure. Can you post that as well? You can ignore that log message as it won't affect the results - its just letting you know you should add an index to the node you a querying.

Comment: You may also want to temporarily remove all the rules and allow anyone to read/write (just to test) to see if the rules are interfering with the query.

Comment: @Jay i have removed the rules, can you help me with a better way to search for username in SearchBar by keystroke. I did a normal test outside the search and it gave me result of users than correspond to the search query, i even used a character as a query and i still get result, but its not working in SearchBar. What i want to achieve is to search for users by username and add then to contact.

Comment: How big is the dataset? Are you searching all users or a limited set? How are the users stored? If you have 1 million users do you really need to query all users?

Comment: @Jay I am searching all users, the users are stored as they signin with there social media account, so i save there email, and fullname. I want a user to add anyone so far they know their username.